# Inject WorkManager with Hilt but getting error "Dagger does not support providing @AssistedInject types."

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager, dagger-hilt

```
While injecting WorkManager using HILT, compiler throwing below error
```

> "Dagger does not support providing @AssistedInject types"

Have followed all mentioned steps from below link

https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack

**PFB Coding snippet and build.gradle dependencies for HILT and Worker**

1. WorkerClass
   [image: Using @HiltWorker and @AssistedInject]
2. Dependencies

[image]

**To Resolve the issue have seen and implemented various S.O. post but no luck.**

> Whereas, if I didn't use both @HiltWorker and @AssistedInject and
> removed other dependencies from object constructor code compiles and
> run successfully but field injection for required dependencies won't
> work.

Therefore not sure whether its library issue or some implementation issue.

**And thank you for your support and answer in advance!**

Edit :
**(Adding WorkerModule.kt code)**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object WorkerModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideWorkerModule(context: Context,
        workerParameters: WorkerParameters
//        appNetworkService: AppNetworkService,
//        appDatabaseService: AppDatabaseService
    ): PaymentTrackerWorker {
//        return PaymentTrackerWorker(context, workerParameters,appNetworkService,appDatabaseService)
        return PaymentTrackerWorker(context, workerParameters)
    }
}
```

Comment: The error appears to be in `di/WorkerModule.java`.  Can you post that module?

Comment: @Nitrodon: Please check have added the code wrt WokerModule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that you are trying to `@Provides` a class with an `@AssistedInject` constructor.  This makes sense: after all, there is no way to get the right instance of `WorkerParameters` in a singleton context.

Fortunately, `WorkerModule` is also completely unnecessary, as `HiltWorkerFactory` already knows how to create any `@HiltWorker`-annotated class.  Simply remove the module, and follow the tutorial to ensure that `HiltWorkerFactory` is installed in `WorkManager`.

Comment: @Nitrodon- Thanks its working now  :)
I think that was the hangover of Dagger2 that's why have created WorkerModule ;)